# Iterate through List looking for similar items to consolidate into new List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

This should be easy to do, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.  I have a List of items that contain a shipper, receiver, order no and item id.  I iterate through this list to create my Model for a View.  I need to consolidate my items that have the same shipper/receiver.

Here is the code for my View:

```
// GET: /Hazmat/Pending
public ActionResult Pending()
{
    PendingViewModel pendingViewModel = new PendingViewModel();
    // Check for shipments created manually pending shipping
    List<HazmatInfo> pending = hazmatRepository.GetHazmatPendingShipping().ToList();
    List<PendingReceiver> pendingReceivers = new List<PendingReceiver>();
    List<HazmatLocation> shippers = new List<HazmatLocation>();
    PendingReceiver pendingReceiver = new PendingReceiver();
    List<PendingItem> pendingItems = new List<PendingItem>();

    foreach (HazmatInfo item in pending)
    {
        PendingReceiver tempReceiver = new PendingReceiver();
        List<PendingItem> tempItems = new List<PendingItem>();

        tempReceiver.Receiver = hazmatRepository.GetLocationById(item.ToBU);
        tempReceiver.Shipper = hazmatRepository.GetLocationById(item.FromBU);
        tempItems.Add(hazmatRepository.convertToPendingItem(hazmatRepository.GetItem(item.InvItemID), item.OrderNo, item.ToBU));
        tempReceiver.PendingItems = tempItems;
        pendingReceivers.Add(tempReceiver);
    }

    pendingReceivers = ConsolidateItems(pendingReceivers);

    pendingViewModel.PendingReceivers = pendingReceivers;

    //To get a distinct result, group by first found items
    foreach (HazmatInfo item in pending.GroupBy(s => s.FromBU).Select(grp => grp.First()))
    {
        HazmatLocation shipper = new HazmatLocation();
        shipper = hazmatRepository.GetLocationById(item.FromBU);
        shippers.Add(shipper);
    }

    pendingViewModel.Shippers = shippers;

    ViewBag.PendingCount = pending.Count();
    return View("Pending", pendingViewModel);
}
```

Here is the code for consolidating my items:

```
private List<PendingReceiver> ConsolidateItems(List<PendingReceiver> pendingReceivers)
{
    var groups = pendingReceivers.GroupBy(x => new { x.Shipper, x.Receiver });

    pendingReceivers = pendingReceivers.OrderBy(s => s.Receiver.Location).ToList();
    List<PendingReceiver> tempReceivers = new List<PendingReceiver>();
    tempReceivers = pendingReceivers.ToList();
    List<PendingItem> tempItems = new List<PendingItem>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (PendingReceiver tempReceiver in pendingReceivers)
    {
        while (i < pendingReceivers.Count - 1)
        {
            if ((pendingReceivers[i].Receiver.Location == pendingReceivers[i + 1].Receiver.Location) &&
                (pendingReceivers[i].Shipper.Location == pendingReceivers[i + 1].Shipper.Location))
            {
                if (tempItems.Count == 1)
                {
                    tempItems.Add(pendingReceivers[i + 1].PendingItems.SingleOrDefault());
                }

                tempItems.Add(pendingReceivers[i].PendingItems.SingleOrDefault());
                tempReceivers[i].PendingItems = tempItems;
                tempReceivers.RemoveAt(i + 1);
            }

            i++;
        }
    }

    return tempReceivers;
}
```

Here is my PendingReceivers class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

namespace Hazmat.Models
{
    public class PendingReceiver : IEnumerable
    {
        public HazmatLocation Receiver { get; set; }
        public HazmatLocation Shipper { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PendingItem> PendingItems { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return this.PendingItems;
        }
    }
}
```

I can picture what I need to do, but can't seem to implement it.

**I've edited my ConsolidateItems method... and added more information like the data I'm using to help with this problem...**

Currently, my ConsolidateItems method seems to work but skips one item (FromBu=02, ToBu=10).

Given this data:

ID  OrderNo         ItemID  Type    Qty FromBU  ToBU

4055    370047528   850265  MANUAL  12.0000 24  01

4069    996564490   582526  MANUAL  1.0000  02  10

4070    996564491   940145  MANUAL  2.0000  70  49

4071    996564492   430051  MANUAL  3.0000  24  60

4072    996564493   851110  MANUAL  1.0000  02  01

4073    996564493   173000  MANUAL  10.0000 02  01

4075    996564493   928002  MANUAL  1.0000  02  01

The last 3 items in this list should be 3 items in PendingReceivers.PendingItems.  My initial query pulls the above data out of my database.  I need to construct my model from this data.  PendingReceiver.Receiver contains my receiver data and PendingReceiver.Shipper my shipper data.  I may be overthinking this too...

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: i would get so confused writing that

Comment: `Hazmat` - this sounds important I sure hope you get this code right

Comment: Expected result representation would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to group items that have the same `Shipper` and `Receiver`? You can do this with LINQ

```
var groups = _pendingReceivers.GroupBy(x => new { x.Shipper, x.Receiver });
```

This will give you an `IGrouping<TKey, PendingReceiver>` where `TKey` is the anonymous type made up of `Shipper` and `Receiver`. You can then use these groups to output into a `List`.

```
// Flatten the groups into a single list
var consolidated = groups.SelectMany(e => e);
```

Here it is all together, see if this works:

```
private List<PendingReceiver> ConsolidateItems(List<PendingReceiver> _pendingReceivers)
{
    return _pendingReceivers
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Shipper, x.Receiver })
        .SelectMany(e => e)
        .ToList();
}
```

The above should work assuming you have [overridden `HazmatLocation.Equals` correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Not sure if this (the `GroupBy`) is going to work on the default equality comparer.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Good eye, I made a note that `HazmatLocation.Equals` should be overridden.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I'll give it a shot Monday morning.

Comment: @DanielImms, I've changed my ConsolidateItems method to match yours and I'm still getting the 7 items from the initial query.  It's not sorting based on Shipper/Receiver.

Comment: @CooperT `.GroupBy(x => new { x.Shipper, x.Receiver })` should group the items by shipper and receiver if you override `HazmatLocation.Equals`. If you did that correctly, split the statement up and inspect what `GroupBy` returns in your debugger.

Comment: @DanielImms, I might not have explained my intention correctly...  My shipper/receiver pairs need to be compared with each item to ship.  If one item's shipper/receiver pair matches another, I want to consolidate.  I think your LINQ statement is looking to see if the shipper and receiver locations are equal?  Sorry for any confusion.  Let me know if I'm reading the evaluation of that LINQ statement correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow :)

This seems to be a stellar use case for [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx), more specifically, the [GroupBy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx).

Check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35667/How-to-Use-LINQ-GroupBy) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You could try this DistinctBy extention method (credit to Jon Skeet):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(
                            this IEnumerable<TSource> source
                             , Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    var set = new HashSet<TKey>();
    return source.Where(element => set.Add(selector(element)));
}

pendingReceivers = pendingReceivers.DistinctBy( pr => new { pr.Shipper
                                                          , pr.Receiver });
```

You will also need to implement `IEqualityComparer` on the `Shipper` and `Receiver` classes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take a step back to where I was doing my original query and found a LINQ statement that gave me what I'd need right off the bat instead of trying to twist the results to my will after the fact...  Thanks to the help from LINQPad which I just discovered this morning.

```
HazmatInfo.Where (h => (h.ShippingFlag.Equals("false") && h.ShippingType.Equals("Manual")))).GroupBy(x => new { x.ToBU, x.FromBU }, y => new { y }).Distinct()
```

Tim

Comment: Now to figure how to get this query to work in my MVC project.